# How do I correctly add line ends with sed?

Tags: sed, newlines

I have several sed statements that at one points uses newlines in the output with `\n` (Actually they are sed's using `$'` with `\\\n`'s`).

However subsequent sed operations that wish to operate on the end of line using `$` do not seem to work.

Should I be using something else as well?

Is there anyway to do it without a literal line
feed?

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you are trying to do? It's difficult to answer your question from a 10,000 feet perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add newline with `\n`, eg the substitute `s/a/a\nb/` will insert a newline followed by b after an a. However, `$` only matches the end of the pattern space, not a newline. You can match a newline with `\n`.